# Database connection with c# computer program and java android application

Tags: c#, android, mysql

Ok im working on something and i have one question if this is even possible. I am doing 2 applications. One will be on the computer and the other will be on android device. On the computer user will input some data that will be stored in the database. The database will be local at my computer. Is there anyway that i connect to the same database with my mobile phone if it is on the same wifi, and store some information to that database from the mobile phone?

And what should i use? sqllite or MySql. Is it better to write the android application in java or in c# with the xamarine?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is wide range of posibilities. You can use SQL,  NoSQL, plain text.. whatever you want. Xamarin Forms can be a good starting point especially using MVVM. With the same logic you can code both the desktop app and the mobile app. Try Catalog, http://catdb.eu. It does the same as you trying to achive.

For Xamarin.Forms there is a good reference book. It is pretty good. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway that i connect to the same database with my mobile phone if it is on the same wifi, and store some information to that database from the mobile phone?

Yes it is. If database is available trough the network you can establish the connection.
Depends on what you're trying to accomplish, I would rather create the data service (using WCF for example) that would expose interface for both desktop and android applications. In this way you will have unified model for working with database. But you can work with database directly as well. There should be plenty of example of how to do that.

> sqllite or MySql

You can work with any of them, it is more task specific then technology specific question. IMO, SqlLite might be a bit easier to use though

> Is it better to write the android application in java or in c# with the xamarine?

Doesn't really matter. I would say if there is no specific reason why you want to chose xamarin, go with java.

Comment: Are there any special setting i need to set to access the local database from my phone over wifi ?

Comment: you have to make your database accessible. In case of SqlLite, you just need to put it in a shared folder and make sure that you can navigate to it (software like ES File Explorer allows you to browse network folders). Not very familiar with MySql, but for MSSQL I had to allow remote connections to the database, then I was able to connect using server name (just like if I was trying to connect to the db locally).